# Linkedin - login problems via python

Tags: python, authentication, linkedin-api

I'm working on school project and first part which is required is login into linkedin account however I have problems with this task. I believe I successfully pass authentization but when I want to continute to news feed I can't get there.

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class LoginController:

    @staticmethod
    def _get_login_parameters(session, url):
        page_content = session.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, "html.parser")
        csrf_param = soup.find("input", {"name": "loginCsrfParam"}).get("value")
        csrf_token = soup.find("input", {"name": "csrfToken"}).get("value")
        sidsring = soup.find("input", {"name": "sIdString"}).get("value")
        return csrf_param, csrf_token, sidsring

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.login_request(self.email, self.password)

    def login_request(self, email, password):
        login_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin"
        submit_login = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit"
        session = re.Session()
        csrf_param, csrf_token, sidsring = self._get_login_parameters(session, login_url)

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'}

        login_data = ({
            "session_key": email,
            "loginCsrfParam": csrf_param,
            "csrfToken": csrf_token,
            "session_password": password,
            "trk": "guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin",
            "sIdString": sidsring
        })

        login_data = {k: str(v).encode("utf-8") for k, v in login_data.items()}

        session.post(submit_login, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
        response = session.get("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/", allow_redirects=True)
        print(BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser").prettify())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginController("username", "pwd")
```

I tried to find some solutions here but most of the examples here did not even work or did not helped me to resolve my problem. Does anybody has any idea?

BTW result of the response request is this:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TiJt.png

Aditional info:
I do not have any error message. The code will just not forward me to expected website.

The URL exists (expected result) ctrlv.link/CWle .. I tried it myself multiple times.

To make code work you have to just add your linkedin credentials (last line of code) and you should be able to see same results in html as I do.

Desired behaviour: to be able to find word "Welcome" in HTML.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
Demonstrate that the URL exists.  Demonstrate the the logic credentials are correct.  Post your full error message and the values of the contributing variables.

Comment: I do not have any error message. The code will just not forward me to expected website . The URL exists (expected result) https://ctrlv.link/CWle .. I tried it myself multiple times. Also you do not need to do anything else with the code except use your  linkedin crededentials and pas them into last line of the code (obviously Im not gonna supply mine) ... if everything works you should be able to find word "welcome" in html.

Comment: Please edit these updates into your question.  (1) They belong there, not in a comment; (2) editing will enable me to remove my down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

because I wasnt able to find out  what might be wrong with the code I decided to use different aproach by using selenium. Here is my solution.

import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.common.exceptions as exceptions

```
class LoginController:

    @staticmethod
    def _linkedin_login(login, pwd):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("Start-mmaximized")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        path = r"your path to chormedriver\chromedriver.exe"
        try:
            new_session = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

        except exceptions.WebDriverException:
            print("[!] Please download new/stable verison "
                  "of Chrome new_session at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads")

        try:
            new_session.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login")
            new_session.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(login)
            new_session.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(pwd)
            new_session.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]").click()
            time.sleep(3)
        except ImportError:
            print("[-] Something went wrong")

    def __init__(self, login, pwd):
        self.login = login
        self.pwd = pwd
        self._linkedin_login(self.login, self.pwd)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    LoginController("username", "pwd")
```

I have maybe one last question. I'm not too good at writing code based on python standards. Is someone here who is developer or more experienced then me and can refactor the code so it looks as it should (I mean if naming is OK in my code, also I'm not sure if I used @staticmethond as it should be used, if the function is not too big and should be devided into more smaller functions etc.) Thank you.